# Nest one array inside an object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and an object and I would like to combine them by nesting the array within the object using JavaScript. I do not want to use lodash, jQuery, or any other library because my project is fairly small and I cannot add that overhead.

This is my current object and array:

```
var myObject = {
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2"
}
var myArray = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "name 1"},
  { "id": 2, "name": "name 2"}
]
```

And this is how I would like it to be structured:

```
var myObject = {
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2",
  "myArray": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "name 1"},
    { "id": 2, "name": "name 2"}
  ]
}
```

I've tried using the JavaScript push() method, but that didn't work for me. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: push it is for Arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an assignment to the object of your array.

```
myObject.myArray = myArray;
```

Be aware that array's are assigned by `reference` by default. So changing either will change both variables.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "array's are assigned by reference by default"? I appreciate the added explanation and would like to use this as a learning opportunity.

Comment: @spookybot so, in JS objects (which Array is actually a subtype of) are assigned by reference and mutable. Which means if I say `var a = {};` and `var b = a;` both a and b contain the same object. so `a.foo = "bar"; console.log(b.foo);//outputs "bar"` this is in contrast to scalar types (numbers, strings, boolean) which are assigned by value. If you want to be able to change `myArray` and `myObject.myArray` independently of each other, you need to make a _copy_ of the array instead. Frequently done via `myObject.myArray = myArray.slice()`. Hope that helps a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

`myObject.myArray = myArray`

```js
var myObject = {
  "key1": "value 1",
  "key2": "value 2"
}
var myArray = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "name 1"},
  { "id": 2, "name": "name 2"}
]

myObject.myArray = myArray

console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myObject.myArray = myArray
```

Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var myObject = {
      "key1": "value 1",
      "key2": "value 2"
    }
    
    var myArray = [
      { "id": 1, "name": "name 1"},
      { "id": 2, "name": "name 2"}
    ];
        
    myObject['myArray'] = myArray;
    
    console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the newest rest and spread syntax, you could also achieve it like this.

```
let myObject = {...myObject, myArray}
```